# right click menu on mouse release (windows behavior)

Tags: windows, mouse, menu

I'm trying to change the behavior of the right click menu in ubuntu 10.10 because I use Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

When you right click you need to hold the right click and select something.

In Windows the is different
right click (release)
select something with left click

Is there a way to change this in ubuntu?

I'm running the ubuntu in vmware 7

Is that behavior normal?

Comment: This is so annoying ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the normal behaviour in Ubuntu. The normal behaviour is the same as you described for Windows.

As far as I know, there is no way to change this right click behaviour.

It might be a problem with running Ubuntu in vmware, although I can't think how this would make a difference. You could try dual booting or using a different virtualisation solution such as virtualbox.

Was it like this when you first installed Ubuntu? Also, are you running Ubuntu or Kubuntu? (You tagged your question with KDE, which is only installed by default in Kubuntu).

Comment: thx for your answer, i'll try the dual boot.  the tag was a mistake.    thx for your help :)

Answer (score 20):

It's really annoying behaviour for mouse when it opens context menu on right-click-down event, I tried to fix it in driver level but I couldn't. 
But I found  very reliable workaround to fix it.

1) Install Easystroke Gesture Recognition from repository

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

2) Open Easystroke then go to preferences tab, in Behavior section click **Gesture Button**

and right click on the rectangular area in **Select a Mouse or Pen Button** window.

3) In Timeout Profile dropdown list pick up **Timeout Off**

That's all! You don't need to add an action

Comment: Thanks a lot, I poured some water into my external Thinkpad USB keyboard and now the right and middle click trigger at the same time so I couldn't scroll any more with the middle click. With this solution, it is bearable again (still some issues but this will do until I get replacement parts).

Comment: This does work, but damn you can now draw on screen with right click... overkill. But right click works as in windows.

Comment: @Cipi you can disable drawing on screen. `easystroke show` >preferences>Method to show gestures>None

Comment: @kenn yes, but they're still being handled. You get the annoying PING when you rightclick-drag, but.. who cares... it works. :D

Comment: The default Ubuntu behavior is kind of mystifying.

Comment: Lifesaver for VSCode and not limited to Ubuntu. I had this annoying context menu closes immediately after right click bug in VSCode where you have to hold right mouse button to be able to select anything in the menu. This easystroke fixes it completely. I am running Manjaro with i3wm.

Answer (score 6):

At least in newer Ubuntu versions, this is a **design decision**.
There seems to be no way to change the default behaviour.

Behavior: click and hold the right button and then release on the chosen menu option.

Sources:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/320259
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=810597
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1988352
- [Mouse clicks when I release the button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178373/mouse-clicks-when-i-release-the-button)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!